# How can I read in the data I brought in from the post request inside of my get request in Python/Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So currently, I was able to read in the data using the post request. However, I am having a hard time trying to use the same data when I am using the get method. What I want to do is reuse some of the variables to eventually produce a table based off of those variables.

**main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
...
import requests, json
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
   if request.method =='POST':
      data = request.get_json()
      p_name = data['name']
      p_type = data['type']
      ...
      p_end = data['end']
      p_step = data['step']
      create_row_data = {'p_name': str(p_name), 'p_type': str(p_type), ... , 'p_end': str(p_end), 'p_step': str(p_step)}
      #print(create_row_data)  
      return jsonify(create_row_data)
   if request.method == 'GET':
      # Not sure how to get create_row_data in here
      # When I try to read in the data, I get an output of null
      return "ok", 200
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not going to have two request methods active at the same time so in your POST you probably want to persist the data in some way and in your GET retrieve that data from somewhere. Or you might only need the POST here, It's unclear what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Hi @BasvanderLinden, what I want to do is use the `create_row_data` anywhere in the `get_data` function. What I also wanted to do with the get request method is that it would use the `create_row_data` and  based off of the `create_row_data` values, it would run a query and return a new dataframe. From here, the new dataframe would go to front end application.